# TypeORM not setting NULL as DateString

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I have the follwing property in my `Customer` entity (using a Postgres DB):

```
@Column({
    type: "timestamptz",
    nullable: true
})
@IsDateString()
cancelationDate: Date | string;
```

I want to be able to change the date (which works) but also to set it `null` (which does not work)

Works:

```
customer.cancelationDate = moment().add({years:100}).toISOString();
```

Throws error:

```
customer.cancelationDate = null;
```

It says `property cancelationDate has failed the following constraints: isDateString`
Is there any way to update this with `null`? Removing the `@IsDateString()` results in not updating the column at all.

Any hint is highly appreciated

Comment: What version of TypeORM? I find no mention of isDateString here: https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference, so where is it coming from?  Since it seems to be looking for a string have you tried: ```customer.cancelationDate = '';```?

Comment: Agreed, this is coming from https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer, sorry I didn't see that